# How can I setup different environments for my production and development environments for Firebase in my react native app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I’m extremely new at this, so please try and be as elaborate as possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently stumbled upon this problem and found solution from [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@brunolemos/how-to-setup-a-different-firebase-project-for-debug-and-release-environments-157b40512164).
I'll breakdown the steps for you and you can read this guide in detail if there are any issues.

1. Create two folders in ./app/src/ in android platform.
2. Copy respective dev/production google-services.json files inside each folder.
3. That's all for android. Now when you build your app as release, It will automatically use release google-services.json.

For ios,

1. Create two folder inside your ./ios folder - Debug and Release).
2. Place appropriate GoogleService-Info.plist file inside these folders.
3. On Xcode, drag both folders to Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources. You can also create these folders directly from xcode which automatically adds them to Copy Bundle Resources.
4. On AppDelegate.m file, inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, replace [FIRApp configure]; with,

   NSString *filePath;

   ## ifdef DEBUG

   NSLog(@"[FIREBASE] Development mode.");
     filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info" ofType:@"plist" inDirectory:@"Debug"];

   ## else

   NSLog(@"[FIREBASE] Production mode.");
     filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info" ofType:@"plist" inDirectory:@"Release"];

   ## endif

   FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
     [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];

Make sure you add necessary imports and configuration on AppDelegate.m

That's it for ios.

To test if it works, build android app using release build for android. For ios change product build schema to release.

Comment: add [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@<Your key>]; inside debug <Key> else <Key> to separate google maps keys for ios. For android I still have not figured out. React-native-config method seems too much work so I setup using these method